# Highcharts bar data labels position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to align the data labels of the following fiddle in the middle of each bar (without success). It seems the that the data label at the top and on the bottom are making this thing look bad. also the tallest's bar label is overlapping with the bar itself.

I looked through the docs but couldn't make this thing look well.

[Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9qLkx1f1/](http://jsfiddle.net/9qLkx1f1/)

Here is the data labels settings:

```
 plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.series.name + "<span style='color:#0D2A4D; opacity:0.5;'> (" + this.y + "%) </span>";
                }
            }
        },
        series: {
             groupPadding: 0,
             minPointLength: 20,
             pointPadding: 0.2, 
             pointWidth: 10
        }
    },
```

Comment: you  need change height

Comment: @AlexWilson, even if the height is big enough there is a problem with the black bar (overlapping with the bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **padding :0** inside plotOptions.

```
 plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                   padding :0, 
             }
        }
 }
```

and set yaxis tickinterval

```
  yAxis: {
        tickInterval : 80,
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9qLkx1f1/14/

Answer (score 0):

Simply Increase height in following code. Hope i have understood you. If i am wrong please correct me

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qLkx1f1/6/)**

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: "bar",
            height: 150, <---- This is the change
            events: {
                redraw: function () {
                    //$(window).trigger('resize');
                },
                load: function () {
                    //$(window).trigger('resize');
                }
            }
        },
```

Hope that is what you were looking for

Comment: I don't have this much of real estate :(

Comment: And even if the height is big enough, what about the black bar label?